# setting a pointer member variable correctly

Tags: c++, pointers, member, setter, ownership

I have a class `L` simplified as follows :

```
class L
{
    private:
        C * _pc ;
    public:
        C * getc() const ; // getter
        void setc(const C * ipc); //setter
        ~L()
        {
            delete _pc ;
        }
};
```

where `C` is another class.

I also have a helper class `CHelper` simplified as follows :

```
class CHelper
{
    C _c ;
    CHelper(L & ic)
    {
        // 1st constructs _c (code omitted);
        // then sets ic's _pc pointer member variable :
        ic.setc(&_c);
    }
};
```

I feel that there will be a problem with the deletion of `_pc` somehow, without being sure. What about it ?

What are the flaws of such an approch ? How can I reach the same "functionality" (setting correctly a pointer member variable) with a correct approach ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: There are indeed issues with your approach. First, when `CHelper` object is destroyed, so is the `_c` member. `_pc` will point to garbage then. Second, `delete _pc;` will attempt a second destruction for the same object. I would suggest looking into std smart pointers.

Comment: Your example will not compile. Inside the class `L` the destructor has the name `~C`. That does not work. Also you should initialize the `_pc` to a nullptr at the construction of the class. As an alternative you can consider smart pointer like `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @AdrianRoman so I should replace the raw pointer `C * _pc` by a smart one and it would solve my issue ? How could I do it ?

Comment: @Hayt typo, edited, sorry

Comment: It would solve it if you are a little careful with the ownership. For example you could use a 'unique' pointer and pass the object around. You won't be able to initialize it like in your example. Look for example into `make_unique` to see how it's done.

Comment: @AdrianRoman If I want to initialize it as in my example, then I should rather use `shared_ptr` ?

Comment: If you really want to use it like that, then you must remove the `delete _pc` and ensure that the CHelper object is not destroyed before any usage of the `_pc` is ceased.

Comment: If you want to use shared_ptr, you'll have to use a shared_ptr not only in L, but also in CHelper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code currently doesn't compile.
`CHelper`'s constructor asks for a `C` object. The `C` class (probably) doesn't have the `setc` method. you probably meant `CHelper(L& ic)`.

Anyway, If your `CHelper` object goes out of scope and is destroyed then the member variable `_c` is destroyed along with it. Leaving you with a dangling pointer in your `L` object. Not only that, but `L` currently also violates the rule of three/five.

If you have access to C++11 I would greatly suggest to replace the raw pointer `_pc` and `_c` with a `std::shared_ptr` if the `CHelper` class is necessary ( and thus removing the `delete` in that destructor) and otherwise a `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: You was right, I corrected the code. `_c` si not a pointer though

Comment: @user10000100_u But for shared ptr management it is required.

Answer (score -3):

Check if  ipc  parameter  is allocating like an array or not, because  you must use delete [] _pc  for arrays.